# How to check a location in 10KM surround of another location in PHP?

Tags: php

I have:

```
$my_location** =array(latitude,longitude);  
$shop_location** =array(latitude,longitude);  
$shop_distribution_circle** =10KM;
```

I want to check that shop have delivery in my location.

Comment: Actually what exactly you want to achieve?Specify your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is basic math.
 Lets imagine this: 
[image]

"A" - `$my_location` 
"B" - `$shop_location`

You already have `"a"` and `"b"`. Now You have to calculate `c` and `check if C <= $shop_distribution_circle`

Pythagorean formula:

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package: https://github.com/thephpleague/geotools

This is the example they use for calculating distance between points:

```
<?php

$geotools = new \League\Geotools\Geotools();
$coordA   = new \League\Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate([48.8234055, 2.3072664]);
$coordB   = new \League\Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate([43.296482, 5.36978]);
$distance = $geotools->distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);

printf("%s\n",$distance->flat()); // 659166.50038742 (meters)
printf("%s\n",$distance->greatCircle()); // 659021.90812846
printf("%s\n",$distance->in('km')->haversine()); // 659.02190812846
printf("%s\n",$distance->in('mi')->vincenty()); // 409.05330679648
printf("%s\n",$distance->in('ft')->flat()); // 2162619.7519272
```